# Type or namespace not found

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, database

hello i am doing a assignment and the program i am using is visual studio 2012 the lab i am getting an error in my behind code in .cs file the error it is giving me is Line 20 and the compilation error message says

```
The type or namespace name 'Player' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
```

Please help me

```
Line 18:     protected void addPlayer(String name, int jersey, String team){
Line 19: 
Line 20:         Player player = new Player(name, jersey);
Line 21: 
Line 22:         if ( String.Equals(team, "team 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

my whole code is

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void addPlayer(String name, int jersey, String team){

        player = new player(name, jersey);

        if ( String.Equals(team, "team 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            listTeam1.Items.Add(player.getName() + "-" + player.getJersey());
        else if (String.Equals(team, "team 2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            listTeam2.Items.Add(player.getName() + "-" + player.getJersey());
    }

    protected int numPlayers(String team)
    {
        if (String.Equals(team, "team 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return listTeam1.Items.Count;
        else if (String.Equals(team, "team 2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return listTeam2.Items.Count;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    protected void buttonLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String addedItem = listTeam2.SelectedItem.Text;

        listTeam2.Items.RemoveAt(listTeam2.SelectedIndex);
        listTeam1.Items.Add(addedItem);


    }

    protected void buttonRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String addedItem = listTeam1.SelectedItem.Text;

        listTeam1.Items.RemoveAt(listTeam1.SelectedIndex);
        listTeam2.Items.Add(addedItem);

    }

    protected void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addPlayer(tbName.Text, int.Parse(tbJersey.Text), radioTeam.SelectedItem.Text);

        tbJersey.Text = "";
        tbName.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the Player class defined?

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error, it means exactly what it says. It doesn't know *what* player is, and therefore it's probably in another namespace. You need a using directive that imports the namespace. If Player is in another assembly, you need to add a reference to that assembly.